# Show that the conditional probability $P(\cdot | C)$ satisfies the axioms of probability, and is thus, indeed, a probability function.

Tags: probability, notation

**The Statement of the Problem:**

For a fixed event $C$ such that $P(C) \gt 0$, show that the conditional probability $P(\cdot | C)$ satisfies the axioms of probability, and is thus, indeed, a probability function.

**Where I Am:**

So, I'm stuck on this one mostly because I don't remember what this "dot" notation means, and can't seem to find anything anywhere on the web or in the text that explains it. Would someone be able to help me out here?

Comment: The dot just tells you where to put the event whose conditional probability you want to evaluate. The original probability $P$ could have been written $P(\cdot)$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A \mid C) =$ the probability of $A$ occurring, given that $C$ already occurred. Take a look at [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability). The notation $P(\cdot \mid C)$ refers to the map $A \mapsto P(A\mid C)$.